# How to access variable in quoted list

Tags: common-lisp

How do I tell Lisp that I want to evaluate a list "as a list", not "as a function"?

```
(let ((x 500)) '(x . nil))
```

When I type this, it returns

```
(X)
```

Good, it hasn't evaluated the list (as I want). But it hasn't replaced the variable x for its value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'e` fully quotes the expression `e` and has no way of knowing which sub-expressions you want to evaluate instead. If you use a backquote instead of a quote, you can then use a comma to unquote subexpressions.

In your example, you can do

```
(let ((x 500)) `(,x . nil))
```

which is equivalent to `'(500 . nil)` since the `x` is unquoted.

Answer (score 4):

Use `list`:

```
(let ((x 500))
  (list x 3))

=> (500 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cactus' answer is great but I though I would throw a little extra info at you :)

In '(x . nil) x is not a variable, it is a symbol. Symbols are used to name things. This distinction seems silly but can really help your intuition to these problems in future.

A 'variable' is the binding between a symbol and a value.

So evaluating x is basically saying 'give me the value that is named by the symbol x'

Functions and variables can be named by **the same symbol** as they are in different namespaces, so.

```
(defun x () "jam")
(defvar x 10)

(print x) ;; prints 10
(print (x)) ;; prints "jam"
```

This is totally valid. Try it out in your repl!

Given that, look again at

```
'(x . nil)
```

x is neither the function or the variable, it is just the symbol.

Hope this helps!